# Connect to an ad-hoc-network in windows 10 only via command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, windows-10, adhoc

I am currently writing a .bat script in which you can choose whether you want to create an ad-hoc-network or connect to one, to make it easy for everyone to connect within windows 8, 8.1 and 10 as the GUI setup was removed.

Well, creating was easy.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=adhocnetwork key= password
netsh wlan start hosted network 
pause
```

But when I want to connect to a network via `netsh wlan connect adhocnetwork`, it says there is no profile called 'adhocnetwork'.
I figured that you first have to create a profile with the network GUI.

So my question is now if there is a way to create a network profile with the command line, so that I can implement that into the bat file.

Thanks for every answer!

Best greetings,

Bant

Comment: [Andy Altmann's answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/6a2def2e-8663-4c19-8fba-c2c4c3f0eb57/create-wireless-profile-in-command-line) appears topmost googling _create a network profile with netsh wlan_

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well, here is my workaround.

Go to the network and sharing center (hope that's right, my system is in German)

Manually create wireless network and type in the name, security type and key.

Remove the tag from 'connect automatically'.

Press 'Done'

Now open the command line and type in the following lines:

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter name=%name% ConnectionType=IBSS

netsh wlan connect name=%name%
```

I am still hoping for a better solution where you don't need to leave the command shell.

Comment: Sadly, a number of Windows systems say BSS isn't a valid type. There's supposedly an answer for that on the Intel forums, but they're down for hours with a "check back in a few minutes" message.